# Performance of OR operation ( || ) vs inArray()

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Suppose that you want to check what input string a user has entered in a form field. Which one would be the fastest way to check this input against a list of possible values?

The following examples use **jQuery**.

First method: using `||`

```
if (input == "firstValue" || input == "secondValue" || ... ) {
    ...
}
```

Second method: using `inArray()`

```
if ($.inArray(input, array) >= 0) {
    ...
}
```

Are there any significant differences between these two methods?

Comment: both have O(n) worst case complexity, where n is the number of things you are testing, the only performance gain would be one is not a function call, whereas the other is.

Comment: Is this really JavaScript you're talking about?

Comment: On a practical level, however, I'd lean towards something like `inArray()` more just for the fact that it has greater potential to be dynamic for large countercheck data sets. As well as being easier to read. Just imagine if we had 10 or so values to countercheck! :D

Comment: @Niko ~ probably jQuery actually. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/

Comment: @Niko LOL sorry, wrong tags :D Edited

Comment: Actually somebody re-tagged your question. If you ask for JavaScript don't post code that looks like PHP (inArray, `$`-prefixed primitive variables)

Comment: Especially that "inArray" part is weird - PHP would be `in_array` while in JavaScript with jQuery it's `if ($.inArray($input, $array) >= 0)`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't want the fastest but the most readable way. And that's `in_array()` (JavaScript: `array.indexOf(value) >= 0`) for more than 2 or 3 values.

The performance difference is negligible - while a function call and array creation certainly has some overhead, it doesn't matter compared to expensive operations such a file access, database access, network access, etc.. So in the end nobody will notice the difference.

Here's a short [benchmark](https://paste.aeum.net/show/77/), each with 1 million iterations:

```
5.4829950332642 - in_array, the array is recreated everytime
2.9785749912262 - in_array, the array is created only once
0.64996600151062 - isset(), the array way created only once and then the values were turned to keys using array_flip()
2.0508298873901 - ||
```

So, the fastest, yet still very readable way is this. Unless you create `$arr` only once and use it **many** times, there is no need for this and you can simply stay with `in_array()`.

```
$arr = array_flip(array('your', 'list', 'of', 'values'));
if(isset($arr[$value])) ...
```

---

In case you *did* ask for JavaScript (in this case **get rid of those `$` prefixes!**), the best solution is using `Array.indexOf()`:

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].indexOf(value) >= 0
```

However, not all browsers already support `Array.indexOf()`, so you might want to use e.g. the function from [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/):

```
_.contains(['a', 'b', 'c'], value)
```

jQuery also has a function for this:

```
$.inArray(value, ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

The fastest way would be with an object and the `in` operator, but the object definition is less readable than the array definition:

```
value in {'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0}
```

Here's a JSPerf benchmark for the various solutions: http://jsperf.com/inarray-vs-or - but again, the rather big performance difference is negligible in most cases since you are not going to execute the code millions of times in a loop.

Comment: IMHO, it's better to shim `Array.indexOf()` than include another whole JS library...

Comment: That's indeed a good idea if all code is written by you and not considered legacy code - if you use `for(var i in array)` somewhere (which you shouldn't), extending `Array.prototype` will break these loops. Besides that, the OP is already using jQuery.

Comment: "So, the fastest, yet still very readable way is this. Unless you create $arr only once and use it many times, there is no need for this and you can simply stay with in_array()." Can you explain this part better please?

Comment: The performance difference is only relevant if the actual check runs lots of times and the array is always the same, i.e. you can create the array one time and then re-use it.

Comment: I see that there is not a big performance difference between creating the array every time and reusing it...

Comment: Yes, for inarray it's true - the overhead of creating an array in JavaScript is minimal. However, the performance gain from using an object instead of an array is huge - but expected as you move from `O(n)` to `O(1)`

Comment: Still, || is the fastest method (after isset). I didn't see that coming.

Comment: It makes sense though - the JavaScript engine actually *knows* what you want to do while it doesn't in the other cases.

Comment: I mean, I was kind of expecting that using an object would be faster.

Comment: Ok, one last thing and then I'll let you free :D What about this: "It makes sense though - the JavaScript engine actually knows what you want to do while it doesn't in the other cases"?

Comment: `inArray` is a function that has to be called every time, the engine does not know that it simply checks if one of the strings in the array is the given value. The `val == '..' || ...` code will be parsed once and then everything is done in the native code of the engine - no JavaScript code is involved while evaluating the expression

Comment: Added tests for underscore and lodash for comparison here: http://jsperf.com/inarray-vs-or/3

Basically lodash.contains is actually on par with arr.indexOf performance-wise in chrome, but indexOf still wins in IE

Answer (score 4):

The answer is, *it depends*...

If there are only a few possibilities, use `if (a || b || c)`.

If there are maybe up to 10, use `Array.indexOf()`

Note that for the two recommendations above, the choice should depend on *readability* and not really on performance.

If there are (many) more than that, use an `Object` with the keys equal to the values, then you can use `if (myVar in myKeyObj)`.  This should give at worst `O(log n)` performance.

Comment: I think he tagged the question incorrectly. His code is PHP, not JavaScript.

Comment: @ThiefMaster why would you think it's PHP? By the fact that he uses dollar prefix? :) having said that, he does rely on boolean outcome of inArray ... man this is confusing

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clear that I'm using jQuery.

Comment: `O(log n)`? Assuming JavaScript uses a hash table for object key lookups it would be `O(1)`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @ThiefMaster that would be implementation dependent - I doubt the ES5 standard specifies it.

Answer (score 2):

Performance usually isnt much of a problem when doing javascript, and usually are hard questions to answer.

In this sample the key difference between solutions is scaling. The first solution will always do a predetermined amount of compares, the inArray solution scales worse because it will compare more if there are more values.

However i'd still go with inArray, 99.99% chance performance really doesnt matter. You want to keep your code maintainable, that is more important.

Comment: `The first solution will always do a predetermined amount of compares`, I thought javascript / php exits early if it gets true in any of the `||`?

Comment: True, so the max will be known.

Comment: Ahh, I see now what you mean by `predetermined`. Thanks

Comment: @TJHeuvel the max will be known?

Comment: Oh, so you mean the maximum number of checks performed?

Comment: And by the way, if there are more values, the first solution will compare more too. So why do you say that the second solution scales worse?

Comment: You cant write all possible values out manually. Thats kinda silly, you dont want to do that at all.

Answer (score 2):

In most languages inArray() is implemented like this:

```
function inArray(needle, haystack) {
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (haystack[index] == needle) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

If you were to unroll that loop, you'd end up doing

```
if (haystack[0] == needle) {
  return true;
} 
if (haystack[1] == needle) {
  return true;
}
if (haystack[3] == needle) {
  return true;
}
// and so on
```

which could be condensed to

```
if (haystack[0] == needle || haystack[2] == needle || … ) {
  return true;
}
```

without changing what is happening under the hood.

---

If you repeatedly have to look up stuff like that, I suggest you get to know maps. instead of

```
var haystack = ['hello', 'world', 'how', 'is', 'life'];
if (inArray("life", haystack)) {
  // …
}
```

you do

```
var haystack = {'hello' : true, 'world' : true, 'how' : true, 'is' : true, 'life' : true};
if (haystack["life"]) {
  // …
}
```

The more elements have to check against, the better the map will perform compared to the array.

Comment: Would I perceive a performance improvement if I need to check against, say, less than 100 elements?

Comment: http://jsperf.com/map-or-array shows that with 10 elements inArray() is faster, but with 26 elements already slower than inMap(). Note that performance of inArray() correlates to number of elements in the array and the position of an element if it can be found. inMap() on the other hand has the same performance regardless of the items to compare.

Comment: ok, so chrome disagrees with firefox on inArray() with 10 elemens being faster. You should get the picture anyways…