# Shorthand for multiple OR expressions in if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a shorthand for the following -

```
if(tld == "com" || tld == "net" || tld == "co" || tld == "org" || tld == "info" || tld == "biz")
{
    //do something;
}
```

Comment: @Hamish It says javascript, I edited the tags accordingly.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10479102/298479 - I explained quite a few methods to do what you want and also linked to a performance comparison in case that matters to you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you could use an array

```
if(["","com","net","co","org","info","biz"].indexOf(tld) > -1) {
     // do something
}
```

or if you are using jquery :

```
$.inArray(tld, ["com","net","co","org","info","biz"])
```

REF - 
[Performance of OR operation ( || ) vs inArray()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479056/performance-of-or-operation-vs-inarray/10479102#10479102)

Comment: You forgot `!= -1` as `0` would be a perfectly valid result (`com`).

Comment: Careful with the first IF code, as an empty string - `["",` - also evaluates to *false*, *undefined* and *null*. Therefore, if **tld** was one of those, he first IF would still pass! Better use `if(["com","net","co","org","info","biz"].indexOf(tld) > -1)`

Comment: Even shorter would be: `if ( ~[...].indexOf(tld) ) { ... }`. Please notice the `~` operator.

Answer (score 12):

Use a regexp:

```
if ( /^(com|net|co|org|info|biz)$/i.test(tld) ) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: how will this handle if tld is "cot" which contains "co"? Ok you added the start and end as I posted.

Comment: @ShalomSam I don't know, that isn't a micro-optimization that I've tested yet.

Answer (score 0):

did you think about using switch statement? something like this:

```
switch(tld)
{
   case 'com':
   case 'net':
   case 'co':
   ...
   ...
   // do something for all of them
   break;
   default:
   // if you want you can have default process here
   break;
}
```

Comment: i did think about it .. but you'd ideally wanna use a switch when you have different executions on different cases. And more over i'm looking for a shorthand, not making my code longer. Thanks for the reply though much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[Bitwise IndexOf Shorthand](https://www.sitepoint.com/shorthand-javascript-techniques/#23bitwiseindexofshorthand)

```
if (~["com", "net", "co", "org", "info", "biz"].indexOf(method)){/*Do somthing if true*/}
if (!~["com", "net", "co", "org", "info", "biz"].indexOf(method)){/*Do somthing if false*/}
```