# Shorthand when using || for comparison (==) rather than assignment (=)

Tags: javascript, php

I've seen lots of questions about the use of || in assignment expressions such as

```
$a = $b || $c
```

but I haven't come across this, so forgive me if it's a duplicate.

Can you abbreviate a comparison used in an if statement such as:

```
if ($a == ($b || $c || $d)...
```

or is it necessary to write it out in full as

```
if ( ($a == $b) || ($a == $c) || ($a == $d) )... ?
```

I'm working in PHP but the question would also apply to JavaScript

Comment: You have to write it out in full

Comment: Yes, it should be written in full

Comment: There are however many tricks, depending on what the variables represent, such as `if ([b,c,d].indexOf(a))` etc. or using in_array and all the other functions in PHP

Comment: For PHP you can use `in_array()`. But really saying something would apply to other languages as well might simply not be the case.

Comment: This question really gets asked a lot.

Comment: _"the question would equally apply to JavaScript"_ - No it wouldn't, because in some languages `||` always returns a boolean value, but in JS it doesn't.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a false assumption that all languages work the in same manner.

Comment: @PeeHaa: You mean they don't? No wonder my C++ won't compile!

Comment: false assumptions don't make a question off-topic. If you're looking to close the question, there are plenty of other (more) valid reasons to pick from (e.g. "dupe").

Comment: @PeeHaa "You tagged this for php and js so here is the answer for php and js. But your assumption is false because not all languages may behave the same."  Seems pretty answerable to me.

Comment: I removed the suggestion that this might apply to any language other than PHP or JavaScript. Sorry if it's a duplicate (I suspected it might be) but it's difficult to phrase a search which brings up earlier questions, mine didn't at any rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you abbreviate a comparison used in an if statement such as `$a == ($b || $c || $d)`

No. The expression in the parenthesis is evaluated first, i.e. `($b || $c || $d)` evaluates to the first truthy value. Lets consider `$b = 0, $c = 'foo', $d = null`, then `($b || $c || $d)` would result in `'foo'`, so you would end up comparing `$a == $c`.

Related: [Shorthand for multiple OR expressions in if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11127753/218196)

(I actually answered this with respect to JavaScript (`$a` is a valid variable name in JS), but it's the same in PHP).

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered, I accepted this as the most illuminating, including the helpful link.

Answer (score 3):

you cannot abbreviate like that. you have to do the full syntax like in your last code block.  if you want to shorten it, you can put the vars you are comparing against `$a` into an array and use `in_array()`.  This will usually work, but not always, depending on what the values actually are. But this isn't all that great anyways, since you are trading off one chunk of code for another, so you aren't really shortening the code.

Alternatively, consider using `switch` instead of `if`, particularly if you need to do something different based on which of those conditions are true.

Answer (score 2):

no, you cannot abbreviate like that.  If you want to compare x to a large number of variables, though, you can use a loop and iterate through the variables you are comparing x to, performing one comparison per iteration of the loop.

Comment: if you're comparing x to 50 other variables you might want to do this...