# Number equals this OR this in Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, match

I am looking at a more elegant way to match and either or in JavaScript.

With strings, we can do the following:

```
"test".match(/test|otherstring/)
```

But the number object has no method match. We can of course add this, but my application will be dropped into a large international site with hundreds of separate applications, so this would be a dangerous move.

At this point I have two options:

```
String(myNumber).match(/test|numbers/)
```

Or:

```
if(number === test1 || number === test2)
```

But neither of these solutions seem very elegant to me. What I would like is to be able to do:

```
number === test1||test2;
```

But the result of this is either true if `number===test1` of if not it returns `test2`. Or use brackets:

```
number === (test1||test2)
```

But this only compares the first test and returns the result of that.

Here we can have a little more fun with JavaScript wierdness. Bonus points for anyone who can tell me why the following sequence occurs:

```
13===(13|13)
# true
13===(12|13)
# true
13===(1|13)
# true
13===(133|13)
# false
13===(13|133)
# false
```

Comment: If `if (num == 1 || num == 2)` doesn't look elegant to you then you need to work on your tastes. ;-) Seriously now, this is the very definition of "natural as a baby's smile". How can it *not* be elegant? I can understand having second thoughts if you had to compare with lots of values, but for just two...

Comment: How about `[test1,test2].some(function(x){return num==x})`?

Comment: *"Bonus points for anyone who can tell me why the following sequence occurs"* Are you aware that you are doing bitwise operations there? `12|13` is `13`. Same for `1|13`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shorthand for multiple OR expressions in if statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127753/shorthand-for-multiple-or-expressions-in-if-statement)

Comment: @Jon As soon as your are needing to do multiple tests on multiple values, this gets very hard to read.

Comment: @MildFuzz: That's true, but it's also not what we can see in the question.

Comment: @Jon I think the implication is clear enough. I don't think editing the question is needed.

Comment: @FelixKling that question is related to strings, mine is explicitly numbers.

Comment: The question uses strings as examples, but it applies to numbers as well. Unless you are dealing with bitmasks, there is no "trick" for numbers that doesn't work for strings as well.

Comment: @MildFuzz: I respectfully disagree. `for` and `while` and `do...while` are functionally equivalent, so if you ask for a suggestion people will pick one based *on the particular use case*. Same with `if/elseif` vs `switch`, and IMO same here.

Answer (score 0):

for this question

```
13===(13|13)
# true
13===(12|13)
# true
13===(1|13)
# true
13===(133|13)
# false
13===(13|133)
# false
```

A single pipe is a bit-wise OR.

example

```
alert(6 | 10); // should show 14
8 4 2 1
-------
0 1 1 0 = 6  (4 + 2)
1 0 1 0 = 10 (8 + 2)
=======
1 1 1 0 = 14 (8 + 4 + 2)
```

Comment: `113|13` is `141`, not `113`. Also, for example, `2|1` results in `3`, not `2`, so your explanation is incorrect. Have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7C_(Bitwise_OR)).

Comment: You fixed your post, but you haven't answered the OP's actual question.