# JavaScript - Shorthand of "Or" inside an if statement

Tags: javascript

Is there a shorthand for "Or" condition inside an if statement, I feel it's stupid to be repetitive, in the below case "a" variable is repetitive to check all the "Or" conditions:

```
  if(a != 'Cancelled' || a != 'Rejected' || a != 'Delivered' || a != 'Confirmed'){

    //execute something here

 }
```

Comment: not really, the best way could potentially be to rewrite the condition using and or just a single flag if possible.

Comment: Another one with basically the same title: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127753/shorthand-for-multiple-or-expressions-in-if-statement Search before you post.

Comment: `a != 'Cancelled' || a != 'Rejected' || ...` will always be true, since if it would be false then `a` must both be `'Cancelled'` and `'Rejected'` (etc.) and that's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (['Cancelled', 'Rejected', 'Delivered', 'Confirmed'].indexOf(a) == -1) {
  // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Great Answer!
Thanks a lot! +1