# JS Short for if (a == b || a == c)

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm searching for a short way to write this:

```
    if ( variable == 1 || variable == 2 || variable == 6)
```

I tried

```
    if (variable == 1 || 2 || 6)
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shorthand for multiple OR expressions in if statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127753/shorthand-for-multiple-or-expressions-in-if-statement)

Comment: write it the long way. it's got the best possible performance because it is simple. Also, it could, depending on the javascript implementation, possibly stop evaluating the statement as soon as one of the equations evaluates to true (that's called lazy evaluation) I don't really know if that's done in javascript. EDIT: It's also really portable.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin: I find it hard to believe your core performance problem in your application is going to be an `if` statement with a couple comparisons.  Generally, readability and maintainability should be preferred over performance in non-critical code, and optimized only when profiling shows there to be a real performance impact in that area.

Comment: @mellamokb true, but what's the real readability gain from Array.indexOf? Also, there's still the portability issue.

Comment: Personal preference really.  If I had more than, say, 5 comparisons, I think an array `indexOf` is easier to parse quickly in my mind than a really wide `if` statement.  It could also be refactored into a helper method, say `if (anyValueMatches(variable, [1,2,6])) ...`

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. I'm going with the array-solution because I have a lot of values which I will be changing a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it by putting your possible values in an array and using [**`Array.indexOf`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
if ([1,2,6].indexOf(variable) != -1)
```

Comment: what is the performance difference on this versus a string of OR tests? do you think this has worse performance? it has a bigger memory foot print for sure, right? (I am aware that the difference is probably negligible, so this is a pretty academic question)

Comment: @hhamilton: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479056/performance-of-or-operation-vs-inarray/10479102

Comment: It should be the same impact. If the interpreter is clever it will see that the list is never modified and marked immutable. Therefore you end up with the same memory footprint and the list will not be recreated on every run. If in doubt create the list first as a variable and keep it for checking.

Comment: Thank you very much for the incredibly fast answer, I guess it's the shortest version.

Comment: @user1630383: Note that this seems to only be supported in IE versions 9 and later.  See the linked references in the comments for some better cross-browser solutions using 3rd-party libraries.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (variable in { 1: 1, 2: 2, 6: 6 }) {
   // ...
}
```

Or (more secured way):

```
if (({ 1: 1, 2: 2, 6: 6 }).hasOwnProperty(variable)) {
   // ...
}
```

Or (not that short, but also works):

```
switch (variable) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 6:
        // ...
        break;
    default:
        // else
}
```

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Then it was a typo. I decided to change answer to more cross-browser solution.

Comment: Fair enough. The first solution is nice.

Comment: The solution does not work for arbitary values. e.g. if `variable` contains an object it will first be converted to a string and then matched. Even worse if `variable` contains the string `__proto__` it will always be true: `"__proto__" in {}`

Comment: @bikeshedder The solution is applied to the described context only.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
[1,2,6].indexOf(variable) >= 0
```

This does not work in IE<9, but you can use a polyfill.
SugarJS provides a [polyfill for indexOf](http://sugarjs.com/api/Array/indexOf) and is a great library.

Comment: The polyfill is only required for IE versions <9 which are still quite common. I updated my answer that only "IE<9" does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

`[1,2,6].includes( variable )`

[browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#browser_compatibility)