# Why '=' and '||' will be evaluated to be true?

Tags: javascript

I read this post, it mentioned this `if (variable == 1 || 2 || 6)` cannot work ([JS Short for if (a == b || a == c)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14607688/8565199)).

But I tried this example, it will be evalauted to be true, why?

```
var a = 'apple';
if('apple2' == a || 'banana' ) {
 alert('hi');
}
```

Here is the working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/Loun1ggj/

Update:
if('apple2' == a || 'banana' ) is not evaluated into if('apple2 == a' || 'apple' == 'banana')?

Comment: Because a non-empty string literal is *always* `true`.

Comment: I hope this answer helps you understand what javascript actually does: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4923684

Comment: The original "cannot work" probably refers to the fact that `variable == 1 || 2 || 6` is always true and doesn't do what's desired; it doesn't mean that the `if` will never be executed (to the contrary).

Comment: Downvoters: Why down vote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break down the expression:

```
if('apple2' == a || 'banana' )
```

The first part to be evaluated is the `==`, because it has highest [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence):

```
'apple2' == a
```

This is a standard [equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators), and returns `false`, giving us:

```
if(false || 'banana')
```

The [`||` operator in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) returns not `true` or `false`, but whichever of its arguments is "truthy". A non-empty string like `'banana'` is considered "truthy", so we end up with this:

```
if('banana')
```

Now we again look at the "truthiness" of `'banana'`, and the if statement proceeds.

Answer (score 1):

`if('apple2' == a || 'banana' )` is evaluated this way:

```
if(('apple2' == a) || ('banana') ), which is:
if :
'apple2' == a // false
||(or)
'banana' // true, since Boolean('banana') is true (a non-empty string is a truthy value)
so => if (false or 'banana') => if ('banana') // => true
```

It's not evaluated as `if('apple2' == a || 'apple2' == 'banana' )`.

Comment: if('apple2' == a || 'banana' )  is not evaluated into if('apple2 == a' || 'apple' == 'banana')?

Comment: @user8565199 Who said that?

Comment: Actually, there's an extra step here, which is that `false || 'banana'` evaluates to `'banana'`, not `true` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) for why). The `if` then asks "is `'banana'` truthy?" and comes up with the answer "yes".

Comment: @Mr Geek, it was my assumption

Comment: @user So `a == 'foo' || b == 'bar'` is evaluated as… what? There's no implicit rewriting going on, only exactly what you write is being evaluated.

Comment: @IMSoP Please read all the answer, I said in the next-to-last line `if (false or true) // => true`.

Comment: @MrGeek But that's not what's evaluated, what's evaluated is `if (false or 'banana')`, which in turn is equivalent to `if('banana')`. Only the `if` actually puts us into boolean context, not the `||`.

Comment: But then when it's evaluated it's `if (true)`.

Answer (score 1):

Since 'banana' is always true, it would always run, see the below example

```js
var a = 'apple';
if('apple2' == a) {
 alert('hi');
}
if('banana'){
  alert('hello');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence%24revision/510297#Table), the operator `==` has higher precedence over operator `||`. So the expression is evaluated as follows:

```
if('apple2' == a || 'banana' )

'apple2' == a //false

'banana' //true (non-empty string)
```

So final evaluation will be, always true:

```
if(false || true) //true
```

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 expressions here

1. 'apple2' == a which resolve to falsy
2. 'banana' which resolve to thruthy

Because 'banana' is not undefined or null  essentially.